# Proving sequence's conjectured formula using mathematical induction

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $u_0,u_1,u_2,\ldots$ be the sequence 
$0, 1, 1/2,3/4, 5/8, 11/16,\ldots$
in which the average of the previous two terms forms the current term, i.e. $$u_{s+2} = \left( \frac{u_{s+1} + u_s}{2}\right)$$
Let $v_s = u_s- u_{s-1}$.

The conjectured formula for $v_n$ is $(-1/2)^{(n-1)}$, but to prove it by induction with the available knowledge of the sequence gets stuck, as shown below.

The basis step is for $n=1$, $v_s = (-1/2)^0 = 1$.
Let, the conjecture be true for $n = k$, and need to prove it for $n = k+1$.

As, $v_k = u_k - u_{k-1}$ `(1)`  is assumed to satisfy the conjecture,
we need prove that $v_{k+1}$ satisfies too, i.e.
$v_{k+1} = u_{k+1} - u_k$ `(2)` 
In other words, need prove that $v_{k+1} = v_k\cdot(-1/2)$.`(3)`

So:
\begin{eqnarray}
v_{k+1} & = & u_{k+1} - u_k \\
& = & (u_k + u_{k-1})/2 - (u_{k-1} + u_{k-2})/2 \\
& = & (u_k - u_{k-2})/2  \qquad \qquad \qquad \ \qquad (4)
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
v_k & = & u_k - u_{k-1} \\
& = & (u_{k-1} + u_{k-2})/2 - (u_{k-2} + u_{k-3})/2 \\
& = & (u_{k-1} - u_{k-3})/2 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (5)
\end{eqnarray}

In order to prove $(4)$ as $v_k\cdot(-1/2)$ is something not possible by me in spite of all attempts so far.

Comment: Please use MathJax for mathematical equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks to all for making the clue visible. Also, would follow MathJax in future, but would also like to learn by seeing markdown code for some special case, from other questions already asked. Is it possible to view that for others?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with $$2u_{n+2}=u_{n+1}+u_n$$ and subtract $2u_{n+1}$ from each side to obtain $$2u_{n+2}-2u_{n+1}=u_n-u_{n+1}$$ or $$u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}=-\frac 12\left(u_{n+1}-u_n\right)$$

From which it is easy to establish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in $(4)$, we have using the recurrence $$u_s=\frac{u_{s-1}+u_{s-2}}{2}$$ that

$$v_{k+1}=u_{k+1}-u_k=\frac{u_{k-1}-u_k}{2}=-\frac{v_k}{2}$$ where in the last step we used the inductive hypothesis